# Javascript appendChild() not working when I try to add image on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an image to a page on button click, but after lots of testing, it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEvenListener('click', event => {

var othermonke = document.createElement("img");
othermonke.src = ""../../Downloads/monke.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""";
othermonke.appendChild(othermonke)
})
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You can't append an element into itself. You need an element already existing in the DOM, ex. `document.body`.

Comment: Teemu is right. Alternatively you could append it to `button.parentElement`;

Comment: just tried all of these. I'm even trying to simply append text but nothing is changing. aaa

Comment: ok, just gimme a minute

Comment: wait, nevermind, turns out i forgot to at an = in the src part. thanks for the help <3

Comment: Oh well, i posted an answer. I'm happy you've found the error xd

Comment: `othermonke.appendChild(othermonke)` obviously doesn't make any sense. Next thing is you cannot use unescaped `"` inside a string for which you're already using `""` as delimiters. And even if that were done correctly, you're overloading the `src` attribute with information that is misplaced there (width, height, alt). How do those infos relate to the source of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, use this. First, there is a type in `addEventListener` (you can check for such errors by doing Ctrl + Shift + J in Chrome and most major browsers). Then , you need to append the image into an element that is already in the DOM. Here, as an example i've used the parent element of your button, whatever that may be:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {

   const othermonke = document.createElement("img");
   othermonke.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/200";
   othermonke.width = "200"; // Better practice is to use setAttribute here
   othermonke.height = "200";
   othermonke.alt = "alttext";

   button.parentElement.appendChild(othermonke);
});
```

```html
<button>btn</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some modifications to your code.

1)You can't create an alement and attach it to itself.

2)Each property should be assigned to the element it self (src, width, height, alt)

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {

var othermonke = document.createElement("img");
othermonke.src = "../../Downloads/monke.jpg";
othermonke.width="200";
othermonke.height="200";
othermonke.alt="";
div.appendChild(othermonke)
})
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
<div>
</div>
```